# Google Sheets Regexreplace for adding year to months

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have a dataset like this:

```
2019-01-02-03-04-05-06-07-08-09-10-11-12
2020-01-02-03-04-05-06-07-08-09-10-11-12
2021-01-02-03-04-05-06-07-08-09-10-11-12
2022-01-02-03-04-05-06-07-08-09-10-11-12
2023-01-02-03-04-05-06-07-08-09-10-11-12
2024-01-02-03-04-05-06-07-08-09-10-11-12
```

All of the content, for each row, in in one sing column.
I want to apply a `regexreplace()` to have a result like this:

```
2019-01,2019-02,2019-03,2019-04,2019-05,2019-06,2019-07,2019-08,2019-09,2019-10,2019-11,2019-12
2020-01,2020-02,2020-03,2020-04,2020-05,2020-06,2020-07,2020-08,2020-09,2020-10,2020-11,2020-12
2021-01,2021-02,2021-03,2021-04,2021-05,2021-06,2021-07,2021-08,2021-09,2021-10,2021-11,2021-12
2022-01,2022-02,2022-03,2022-04,2022-05,2022-06,2022-07,2022-08,2022-09,2022-10,2022-11,2022-12
2023-01,2023-02,2023-03,2023-04,2023-05,2023-06,2023-07,2023-08,2023-09,2023-10,2023-11,2023-12
2024-01,2024-02,2024-03,2024-04,2024-05,2024-06,2024-07,2024-08,2024-09,2024-10,2024-11,2024-12
```

That is basically replacing each `"-"` by the first 4 numbers in the corresponding row.

As I know those are the year in the first part and the months in number in the second part, I know I can used the following formula to have the expected result:

```
=regexreplace(A1,"^([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{1,2})-([0-9]{1,2})-([0-9]{1,2})-([0-9]{1,2})-([0-9]{1,2})-([0-9]{1,2})-([0-9]{1,2})-([0-9]{1,2})-([0-9]{1,2})-([0-9]{1,2})-([0-9]{1,2})-([0-9]{1,2})","$1-$2,$1-$3,$1-$4,$1-$5,$1-$6,$1-$7,$1-$8,$1-$9,$1-$10,$1-$11,$1-$12,$1-$13")
```

PS.: my data is in A1

But how to have something more dynamic, to replace several parts of the string with one portion of the same string?

Comment: You won't be able to do that with one `regexreplace`.

Answer (score 2):

Would you really want `REGEXREPLACE`? Alternatively:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,LEFT(A1,5)&SPLIT(MID(A1,6,LEN(A1)),"-")))
```

Using `REGEXREPLACE`, maybe something like:

```
=LEFT(A1,7)&REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(\d{4}-\d{2})?(-)",","&LEFT(A1,5))
```

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(TEXT(INDEX(SPLIT(A1:A, "-"),,1)&"-"&
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A1:A, "-")), "offset 1", 0)), "yyyy-mm")))
```

[image]

then:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFERROR(
 TEXT(INDEX(SPLIT(A1:A, "-"),,1)&"-"&
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A1:A, "-")), "offset 1", 0)), 
 "yyyy-mm")&",")),,999^99)), ",$", ))
```

[image: 0]

or without spaces:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFERROR(
 TEXT(INDEX(SPLIT(A1:A, "-"),,1)&"-"&
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A1:A, "-")), "offset 1", 0)), 
 "yyyy-mm")&",")),,999^99)), " |,$", ))
```